# Jenkins build failed: Could not find dependency version in maven remote repo

Tags: maven, jenkins

I created a new version in the one project, the version is x.xx.x-SNAPSHOT and used in another project as an external library then pushed it. now Jenkins build is failed.

it's saying that this new dependency is not found in my company repo. I don't have an idea how to fix this.

**ERROR: The POM for jar: X.XX.X-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available**

**Could not find artifact :jar: X.XX.X-SNAPSHOT in artifactory (maven.xx.xx/repo)**

could you please help me?

Thank you

Comment: We need the error message.

Comment: Have you looked up if the POM exists?

Comment: Could you please add the full error log output to the question itself?

Comment: yes, POM is exists.

Comment: The error does not contain the artifact coordinates. Please show us the part of the POM where the dependency is declared.

Comment: It's fixed now. the problem was, i haven't upload new version in maven remote repo(my company repo). now I did mvn deploy. then it's uploaded and jenkins found the needed dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fixed now. the problem was, i haven't upload new version in maven remote repo(my company repo). now I did **mvn deploy**. then it's uploaded and jenkins found the needed dependency.